# Delegate is being released in case of custom View created with XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, delegates

I have created **MyCustomView.xib/h/m:** which extends `UIView` class. Then in my Main.storyboard, put `UIView` object, changed the class to **MyCustomView** and linked to **MainController.h**. So, MainController contains reference to MyCustomView instance.
For loading from xib, in MyCustomView I do the following:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self) {
    if (self.subviews.count == 0) {
      [self commonInit];
    }
 }
 return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
     [self commonInit];
   }
   return self; 
}

- (void) stretchToSuperView:(UIView*)view
{
   view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);
   NSString *formatTemplate = @"%@:|[view]|";
   for (NSString * axis in @[@"H",@"V"]) {
     NSString * format = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatTemplate,axis];
     NSArray * constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint      constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings];
    [view.superview addConstraints:constraints];
 }    
}

- (void)commonInit
  {
    MyCustomView* view = nil;
    NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];
   view = views.firstObject;
   [self addSubview:view];
   [self stretchToSuperView:views.firstObject];
 }
```

This works quite well, until I want to declare delegate in MyCustomView in order to notify MainController to any change(button click, etc). So, my ManController conforms  `MyCustomViewDelegate` and implements methods.

**EDIT 1** setting delegate

```
//MainViewController.m file
@interface MainViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyCustomView *customView;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.customView.delegate = self;
 }
```

The problem here is that delegate becomes nil and I don't understand the reason, so don't know what's the mistake.

**Edit 2** I think somehow I have 2 different instances of MyCustomView.
I have added new property in MyCustomView:

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *firstItem;
@property(nonatomic, weak)id <MyCustomViewDelegate> delegate;
// this is test property  
@property(nonatomic, assign)int testProperty;

@end
```

And when I set this property in viewDidLoad and then click to first button, I see that testProperty has value 0. So, this could mean something wrong with IBOutlet MyCustomView *customView.

Comment: @Rob yes, delegate is weak. ViewController can't be deallocated as it's front controller, and it is actually single controller I have in my experimental project.

Comment: customView is not nil. I linked MyCustomView from Main.storyboard just to controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, that you have two view objects. The one that you added to the storyboard and the one you created via `loadNibNamed`.

Bottom line, `loadNibNamed` will create the view for you (assuming that you've specified `MyCustomView` as the base class for the view specified in the NIB; you can leave NIB's "File owner" blank). You can then write a convenience method in `MyCustomView` to instantiate the NIB-based view:

```
+ (instancetype)myCustomViewWithDelegate:(id<MyCustomViewDelegate>)delegate {
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:delegate options:nil];
    MyCustomView *view = array.firstObject;
    NSAssert([view isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]], @"Base class of NIB's top level view is not MyCustomView");
    view.delegate = delegate;

    return view;
}
```

Then, rather than specifying the view on the storyboard, you must instantiate and add it to the view hierarchy programmatically, e.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyCustomView *view = [MyCustomView myCustomViewWithDelegate:self];   // since `self.myCustomView` should be `weak`, let's hold the view in local variable
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    self.myCustomView = view;                                            // then set the property after the view is safely added to view hierarchy

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"myCustomView" : self.myCustomView};
    self.myCustomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myCustomView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[myCustomView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // ...
}
```

Obviously, when adding a view programmatically, you have to specify its `frame` and `autoresizingMask`, or use constraints like shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't make a simple comment, so I have to ask, and give advices as 'answer'.

First of all, I don't see where do you set the delegate to your MainController, but I think in the viewDidLoad() of the controller.

Second thing. It's really important how do you setup your MyCustomView.xib, because you create a brand new object MyCustomView, and its properties will be unavailable from the controller.

`MyCustomView* view = nil;
    NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];
   view = views.firstObject;
   [self addSubview:view];`

Without knowing the setup of the xib, and setting method of the delegate, here is my guess what could help you:

1. In MyCustomView.xib set the class of the rootView to UIView.
2. In MyCustomView.xib set the class of the File's Owner to MyCustomView
3. Create your subview as a UIView.

   `UIView* view = nil;
   NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];
   view = views.firstObject;
   [self addSubview:view];`

   4. Set the delegate of the myCustomView object in your controller.

`self.myCustomView.delegate = self;`

I hope it will help, if not, then please extend your question with the delegate setter code block, and your xib setup method. (class of file's owner, class of root view etc)